# How can this vector equal 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

In the picture below you can see that

$$\frac{2}{9}AB\cdot AB+\frac{4}{9}AB\cdot AD-\frac{1}{9}AD\cdot AB-\frac{2}{9}AD\cdot AD$$

equals to

$$\frac{2}{9}\left|AB\right|^2+0-0-\frac{2}{9}\left|AD\right|^2.$$

How can

$$AB+\frac{4}{9}AB\cdot AD-\frac{1}{9}AD=+0-0\quad\quad?$$

I don't understand the logic. [The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7PXfl.png) and [The square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Ksd.png):

edit: How can $\frac{2}{9}\left|AB\right|^2-\frac{2}{9}\left|AD\right|^2=0$?

Comment: It seems $A,B,D$ are chosen such that $\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot \overrightarrow{AD} = 0$

Comment: Ok, how can $\frac{2}{9}\left|AB\right|^2-\frac{2}{9}\left|AD\right|^2=0$? @achillehui

Comment: ... and the picture is...?

Comment: Apparently $|AB|=|AD|$ as well, but without the actual diagram showing how these points $A$, $B$, $D$ are arranged, how are we to know?

Comment: I added the picture of the points. @JaapScherphuis

Comment: So $AB$ and $AD$ are sides of a square. That means they have the same length (hence $|AB|=|AD|$) and are perpendicular (hence $\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot \overrightarrow{AD} = 0$).

Comment: Ok! But why is $\frac{2}{9}\left|AB\right|^2-\frac{2}{9}\left|AD\right|^2=0$? @JaapScherphuis

Comment: $|AB|=|AD| \implies |AB|^2=|AD|^2 \implies \frac29|AB|^2=\frac29|AD|^2$

Comment: Oh I see, so the point is that $\left|AB\right|^2-\left|AD\right|^2=0$ and  $\frac{2}{9}\left|AB\right|^2-\frac{2}{9}\left|AD\right|^2=0$ so this ends up being the zero vector? @JaapScherphuis

Comment: It is the real number zero, it is not a vector. The whole expression started from taking the dot product of two vectors, and the result of a dot product is a real number, not a vector. And here $|AB|$ and $|AD|$ are lengths, so again real numbers and not vectors.

Comment: Is logic here the $\frac{2}{9}\left|AB\right|^2-\frac{2}{9}\left|AD\right|^2=0$ the same as $1cm-1cm=0$? @JaapScherphuis